# How can I do the equivalent of "SHOW TABLES" in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to do a lookup of tables in my SQL Server 2005 Express database based on table name. In `MySQL` I would use `SHOW TABLES LIKE "Datasheet%"`, but in `T-SQL` this throws an error (it tries to look for a `SHOW` stored procedure and fails).

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This will give you a list of the tables in the current database:

```
Select Table_name as "Table name"
From Information_schema.Tables
Where Table_type = 'BASE TABLE' and Objectproperty 
(Object_id(Table_name), 'IsMsShipped') = 0
```

Some other useful T-SQL bits can be found here: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/28529

Comment: Why is that ridiculously complex

Answer (score 60):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but why not just use the much simpler [sp_tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186250.aspx)?

```
sp_tables 'Database_Name'
```

Comment: This is a much better solution -- I can actually memorize it! Thanks

Comment: This gives all the tables, rather than just the user tables. So useful, but it depends which interpretation one takes of the question (as the OP was not specific as to whether they wanted all tables or just their own tables)

Comment: [sp_tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tables-transact-sql) does not take a database name as parameter. The (optional) first parameter is the table name. Wildcards are allowed, so the T-SQL equivalent of MySQL's `SHOW TABLES LIKE 'Datasheet%'` is `EXEC sp_tables 'Datasheet%'`

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
USE your_database
go
Sp_tables
go
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Datasheet%'
```

Answer (score 7):

One who doesn't know the TABLE NAME will not able to get the result as per the above answers.

TRY THIS

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo';
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'yourTableName'
```

also look for other `information_schema` views.

Answer (score 4):

And, since [INFORMATION_SCHEMA is part of the SQL-92 standard](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/666.cfm), a good many databases support it - including [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html).

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE
table_name LIKE 'Datasheet%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try it :

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

`MS` is slowly phasing out methods other than `information_schema` views. so for forward compatibility always use those.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I've just come across it.

Normally I would say access the information_schema.tables view, but on finding out the PDO can not access that database from a different data object I needed to find a different way. Looks like `sp_tables 'Database_Name` is a better way when using a non privileged user or PDO.