# How do I get list of all tables in a database using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-table

What is the best way to get the names of all of the tables in a specific database on SQL Server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124205/how-can-i-do-the-equivalent-of-show-tables-in-t-sql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465014/list-table-names, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454986/is-there-a-quick-way-to-report-database-metadata-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Does `SHOW TABLES` (as used in MySQL) work?

Answer (score 1687, accepted):

SQL Server 2000, 2005, 2008, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 or 2019:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

To show only tables from a particular database

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM [<DATABASE_NAME>].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

Or,

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
    AND TABLE_CATALOG='dbName' --(for MySql, use: TABLE_SCHEMA='dbName' )
```

PS: For SQL Server 2000:

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'
```

Comment: Add the database name if you are not using the specific database so it will be SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM <DATABASE_NAME>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables

Comment: Adding `WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'` will include only base tables (and by extension you could always use `WHERE TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW'`).

Comment: "sysdiagrams" appears in this list too :(

Comment: sysdiagrams is a normal table, you always have to exclude it manually with a `AND name <> 'sysdiagrams'`.

Comment: and if one wish to list only table names, one would use name in place of the * like below


  select name from sysobjects where xtype='U' and name ,. 'sysdiagrams'

Comment: Re. the "AND TABLE_CATALOG='dbName'" form: I presume that's to avoid the `use` Statement (hard-coded or via Dynamic SQL).  However, unless I first did `use dbName` (via via SSMS 2016 on SS 2008R2, 2012 and 2014), the "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" Table would contain Rows only for the currently `use`'ed Table.

Comment: Re. `xtype='U'` to exclude non-user created Tables: When I tried it via SSMS 2016 on SS 2008R2, 2012 and 2014, `xtype='U'` also on non-(*explicitly*) user-created Tables with the following prefixes: "sys", 
"MSpeer_", "MSpub_identity_range", "MSreplication_", "MSsubscription_, "MSsnapshotdeliveryprogress" and there appeared to be no other Column on either `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` or `SYSOBJECTS` Tables that could be used to differentiate.

Comment: select name from sys.tables <- from an answer down below. Would be nice to have this added to the most upvoted answer. Also important to note: this query only returns user tables.

Answer (score 209):

```
SELECT sobjects.name
FROM sysobjects sobjects
WHERE sobjects.xtype = 'U'
```

Here is a list of other object types you can search for as well:

- AF: Aggregate function (CLR)
- C: CHECK constraint
- D: Default or DEFAULT constraint
- F: FOREIGN KEY constraint
- L: Log
- FN: Scalar function
- FS: Assembly (CLR) scalar-function
- FT: Assembly (CLR) table-valued function
- IF: In-lined table-function
- IT: Internal table
- P: Stored procedure
- PC: Assembly (CLR) stored-procedure
- PK: PRIMARY KEY constraint (type is K)
- RF: Replication filter stored procedure
- S: System table
- SN: Synonym
- SQ: Service queue
- TA: Assembly (CLR) DML trigger
- TF: Table function
- TR: SQL DML Trigger
- TT: Table type
- U: User table
- UQ: UNIQUE constraint (type is K)
- V: View
- X: Extended stored procedure

Comment: The aliasing is a bit redundant: `SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'U'` would do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, initially i tried this with multiple select statements for `PK,FK,D,C,V,UQ` etc to compare source and target database, but then i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/685073/2218697) feature in VS, but  is there not a `sql query` to compare complete source and target database ?

Comment: One wonders why `'U'`is used to identify the User Table... as opposed to maybe `'UT'` or, the most intuitive, `'T'`...Ah well, this works!

Comment: Is there a way to query the crosswalk of object types to type names so it could be easily joined?

Answer (score 119):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM Sys.Tables
```

Comment: Just a note that (as mentioned in other answers) sys.tables is only available in 2005 onwards

Comment: Which is not a problem in 2018. I think this should be higher :-)

Answer (score 34):

```
USE YourDBName
GO 
SELECT *
FROM sys.Tables
GO
```

OR

```
USE YourDBName
GO
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
GO
```

Comment: select * from [databaseA].sys.tables also works, if you need to access table list of a different database same session.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables
where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 10):

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'print ''?'''
```

Answer (score 10):

`select * from sysobjects where xtype='U'`

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT name 
FROM sysobjects 
WHERE xtype='U' 
ORDER BY name;
```

(SQL Server 2000 standard; still supported in SQL Server 2005.)

Answer (score 7):

The downside of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` is that it also includes system tables such as `dtproperties` and the `MSpeer_...` tables, with no way to tell them apart from your own tables.

I would recommend using [`sys.objects`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql) (the new version of the deprecated  [sysobjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysobjects-transact-sql) view), which does support excluding the system tables:

```
select *
from sys.objects
where type = 'U'      -- User tables
and is_ms_shipped = 0 -- Exclude system tables
```

Answer (score 7):

Any of the T-SQL code below will work in SQL Server 2019:

```
-- here, you need to prefix the database name in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM [MSSQL-TEST].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;

-- The next 2 ways will require you to point
-- to the specific database you want to list the tables

USE [MSSQL-TEST];
-- (1) Using sys.tables
SELECT * FROM sys.tables;

-- (2) Using sysobjects
SELECT * FROM sysobjects
WHERE type='U';
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE 2022**:
You can **list/show** the tables that you created with this simple query in **Microsoft SQL SERVER**.

```
select * from SYS.TABLES;
```

Comment: FYI This does not include the table schema in the results. Which was big deal for me,  but the old `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ` does.

Comment: WHERE schema_id = <integer>  (for me DBO was ID 1)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT sobjects.name
FROM sysobjects sobjects
WHERE sobjects.xtype = 'U'
```

Comment: `SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U' AND name <> 'sysdiagrams';` 
because the sysdiagrams table although created by Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is technically not a system table but one we usually like to exclude anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Well you can use *sys.objects* to get all database objects.

```
 GO
 select * from sys.objects where type_desc='USER_TABLE' order by name
 GO
```

OR

```
--  For all tables
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
GO 

  --- For user defined tables
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
GO

  --- For Views
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_TYPE='VIEW'
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

In SSMS, to get all fully qualified table names in a specific database (E.g., "MyDatabase"):

```
SELECT [TABLE_CATALOG] + '.' + [TABLE_SCHEMA] + '.' + [TABLE_NAME]
FROM   MyDatabase.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
WHERE  [TABLE_TYPE] = 'BASE TABLE' and [TABLE_NAME] <> 'sysdiagrams'
ORDER BY [TABLE_SCHEMA], [TABLE_NAME]
```

Results:

- MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable1
- MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable2
- MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable3
- MyDatabase.MySchema.MyTable4
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
--for oracle
select tablespace_name, table_name from all_tables;
```

---

This link can provide much more information on this
[topic](http://onewebsql.com/blog/list-all-tables)

Comment: This is not for SQL Server, so is not an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this. You will get table names along with schema names:

```
SELECT SYSSCHEMA.NAME, SYSTABLE.NAME
FROM SYS.tables SYSTABLE
INNER JOIN SYS.SCHEMAS SYSSCHEMA
ON SYSTABLE.SCHEMA_ID = SYSSCHEMA.SCHEMA_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ray Vega, whose response gives all user tables in a database...

> exec sp_msforeachtable 'print ''?'''

sp_helptext shows the underlying query, which summarises to...

```
select * from dbo.sysobjects o 
join sys.all_objects syso on o.id =  syso.object_id  
where OBJECTPROPERTY(o.id, 'IsUserTable') = 1 
and o.category & 2 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` also shows you all tables and related columns.

Answer (score 1):

To remove tables added by replication and any other table Microsoft adds run this:

```
SELECT s.NAME SchemaName, t.NAME TableName
FROM [dbname].SYS.tables t
INNER JOIN [dbname].SYS.SCHEMAS s
ON t.SCHEMA_ID = s.SCHEMA_ID
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped=0 and type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
ORDER BY s.NAME, t.NAME
```

Comment: So, this will work to solve OP's question, with the exception of the WHERE clause?

Comment: Where clause removes tables microsoft adds and any system replication tables