# How to output duplicate patients side by side

Tags: sql

I have this data:

```
last name, first name, dob, id
gomez, allan, 10/1/2000, 1
gomez, allan, 10/1/2000, 2
```

The output I want:

```
col1 pat1 pat2
------------- ----------- ------------
last name gomez gomez
first name allan allan
dob 10/1/2000 10/1/2000
id 1 2
```

The patient column "pat1" will be dynamic, so it can have pat1, pat2, pat3 if there are multiple duplicates.

Comment: thank you for correcting my questions.

Comment: Do you want this side by side output as result of your SQL query?

Comment: Hi, it will be easier for the person to identify if the data can be merge if duplicate matches demographic information.  So, I want the output side by side output as a result. thanks

Answer (score 0):

to check if you have patients duplicate you need to select a column to check it using HAVING

```
SELECT * FROM PATIENTS WHERE [last name] IN (
    SELECT [last name]
    FROM patients
    GROUP BY [last name]
    HAVING COUNT([last name]) > 2;
)
```

to put it in the output format that you want you could use a temp table using something like this
[Creating and Selecting table variables dynamically in SQL Server stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300547/creating-and-selecting-table-variables-dynamically-in-sql-server-stored-procedur)

but i will not recommend you to do this because is very difficult and unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, given the output you want.

For example, this data won't be possible to put in the output format you want:

```
last name, first name, dob, id
gomez, allan, 10/1/2000, 1
gomez, allan, 10/1/2000, 2
doe, john, 10/1/2000, 3
doe, john, 10/1/2000, 4
```

That would result into:

```
col1 pat1 pat2 pat3 pat4
------------- ----------- ------------
last name gomez gomez doe doe
first name allan allan john john
dob 10/1/2000 10/1/2000 10/1/2000 10/1/2000
id 1 2 3 4
```

Which is not very readable.

To retrieve all duplicates you could use a query like:

```
SELECT [last name], [first name], dob, COUNT(1) [duplicate count]
FROM patient
GROUP BY [last name], [first name], dob
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

This would return:

```
last name, first name, dob, duplicate count
gomez, allan, 10/1/2000, 2
doe, john, 10/1/2000, 2
```