# Dynamically generated SQL security concerns (sql injection etc.)

Tags: sql, ado.net, sql-injection

We are in the process of developing an "API" for one of our products. This will allow the user to define which columns they wan't to return from their "queries" and we will build the needed SQL.

I know that you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attacks. However is there any security risks when building a statement where the columns returned are defined by the users? Lets say we have the following api request. This is just an example to illustrate what I mean :)

```
/api/customers/getall?fields=Name,Phone,Email&where=Zip=1000
```

The SQL will be

```
SELECT Name, Phone, Email FROM Customers WHERE Zip = @Zip
```

I'm not thinking about just taking the fields parameter and building the SQL directly around that, it will probably be made into a list and returned with some default columns like Id and Modified.

What should you be aware of in this situation? And how would you protect against attacks?

-- Christian

Answer (score 0):

Create a Stored Procedure

This will let you check the input Stings and you should be on the safe side.

See:
[MSDN Create Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669.aspx)

Comment: Stored procedures are not an option for us. It should work without us needing to modify the database specifically for this API.

Also how would you create a SP that dynamically generates the proper SQL given a set of columns to return?

Answer (score 0):

First, I do a query to get the fields of the selected table(s) from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS metadata table.

[Querying database metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database)

The column names pulled from the database are safe to use.  Then I compared the fields in the SELECT clause with the "safe fields list".  If one of the selected fields isn't on the clean list, then remove it or don't run the generated SQL at all.