# Complete Tables and Its Columns of specific DB, how to get in sql server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i want to collect the details of complete tables and views of a specific database, especially here i want only tables/views with its columns structure.
Example : Database having around 561 Tables and Views, please give me a query or some alternate help to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return the required data:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, ORDINAL_POSITION,
   COLUMN_DEFAULT, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,
   NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX, NUMERIC_SCALE,
   DATETIME_PRECISION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

Taken from the following SO question and adding and ORDER BY clause:

[Getting list of tables, and fields in each, in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database)