# How can I look up column names in a SQL Server with an odd schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select column names in our database and I'm unsure how. I tried some solutions I found on Stack Social but I haven't been able to make them work.

Is it even possible given the schema? I feel like it should be but my limited understanding in how to change the FROM clause is preventing me from doing this on my own. Below is a picture to help elaborate on the difficulty I'm having.
[Picture of schema and attempts to return table and column names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBh7d.png)

EDIT: The problem is unique in that the overall layout of our database seems largely different from the norm. There seems to be nested databases and I wasn't sure how to use a specific DB.

The Use function worked well for this but its not intuitive from other answers. At least the picture can help someone in the future if they have a similar problem.

Comment: Use Sys.Columns.   Every database doesn't have its own Columns table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting list of tables, and fields in each, in a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database)

Comment: It may be do-able with sys.columns but its not very intuitive. I tired a basic query ..

Select c.name as c, t.name as t
from sys.COLUMNS
JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id

but got 2 errors:
The multi-part identifier "c.object_id" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "c.name" could not be bound.

If there is an online resource that can better elaborate how to interpret the solution to the other problems, I would greatly appreciate the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use RatManreport
GO

SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%CD%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept the answer once it lets me (3 minutes need to pass). Do you by chance have a link to an online resource where I can learn more about this on my own? I hate asking others for help as I feel I come off lazy. Thanks again!

Comment: @Richard Hansell
Thanks. I see that the above solution can be re-written to not require the Use statement if the FROM statement is written as follows:
FROM DatabaseName.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS