# How to get all tables and column names in SQL?

Tags: sql

I want a list of table names and columns within that table (see below). 
Is there a SQL query that would allow me to do this within a schema?
[image: Result I want]
I know I can look at the GUI interface to look at the table names and columns but there are too many to look at manually.

Comment: This can be done, but the query is different for each SQL product.  Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using SQuirreL SQL Client snapshot. I am not sure if that's the SQL product you mean.

Comment: No, it will depend on what the underlying SQL engine is (SQL Server, DB2, SQLite, etc).  Unless Squirrel contains a database agnostic way to report this information.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

however your question isn't enough clear but you can get all of it with this this code

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES if that's not obvious, note that the columns are different

Answer (score 5):

**Using OBJECT CATALOG VIEWS:**

```
SELECT T.name AS Table_Name ,
   C.name AS Column_Name ,
   P.name AS Data_Type ,
   P.max_length AS Size ,
   CAST(P.precision AS VARCHAR) + '/' + CAST(P.scale AS VARCHAR) AS Precision_Scale
FROM   sys.objects AS T
   JOIN sys.columns AS C ON T.object_id = C.object_id
   JOIN sys.types AS P ON C.system_type_id = P.system_type_id
WHERE  T.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE';
```

**Using INFORMATION SCHEMA VIEWS**

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA ,
   TABLE_NAME ,
   COLUMN_NAME ,
   ORDINAL_POSITION ,
   COLUMN_DEFAULT ,
   DATA_TYPE ,
   CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH ,
   NUMERIC_PRECISION ,
   NUMERIC_PRECISION_RADIX ,
   NUMERIC_SCALE ,
   DATETIME_PRECISION
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
```

Taken from this answer:
[Getting list of tables, and fields in each, in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database)

Comment: @Eric Do you have a better solution ?

Comment: @ShahrozShaikh I don't use squirrel, so I don't have a solution.  But the point is don't post a query that won't work as an answer because it's useless to the OP.  OP can't use it.