# How can I get all tables and columns from a database? (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

I would like to get all tables and their columns in one  table.

For example:

```
Table 1 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | 

Table 2 | Column1 |

Table 3 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5

Table 4 | Column1 | Column2 |

Table 5 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5

Table 6 | Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7
```

EDIT:

Version I'm using: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2550.0 (X64)

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database

Comment: @Larnu Not entire true, he wants it all to be in one table. Not to select all via information schema..As far as i can read.

Comment: @Thomas that's unclear from their post. Especially as, if it is one table, their expected output has a variable amount of columns per row (an impossibility in SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

> As jarlh points out - You need to be sure that the datatypes for each
>   column is of same type otherwise you cannot union them.
>
> So if col1 is normally an Integer, you cannot have col1 with string
>   values. Unless you convert it to string.

If it should just be static do like this:

```
Select Col1,Col2,Col3 from Table1
union all
Select col1,null as Col2, null as Col3 from table2
```

And so on.

So if you largest table has 7 columns
it should be

```
Select col1, col2,col3,null as col4,null as col5,null as col6,null as col7 from table1
union all
select col1, null as col2, null as col3.................. ,null as col7 from table2
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that the column data types must be compatible.

Comment: @jarlh True :) Forgot that part - Thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Use below query .

```
SELECT t.name as TableName, 
stuff(
        (select '|'+ CAST(c.name as varchar(max)) from sys.columns c
    where c.object_id = t.object_id for xml path('')),1,1,'') as columnlist
from sys.tables t
```

Comment: Your stuff is removing to many characters. You may consider correcting this

Comment: I checked it and it's not removing any characters.Let me know if you found any case for same.

Comment: I suggest you check again. You are adding 1  character and stuffing 2 characters

Comment: I got it and update the code. Thanks