# Cannot retrieve ALL datatable names from database

Tags: c#, sql, datareader, reportbuilder, catalog

I am developing some code to tabulate the datatable names and their corresponding columns from a database. I want to have the list that I can see on the MS SQL Report Builder - Query Designer:

[image: Query designer from Report Builder]

Here's my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = server; Initial catalog = Catalog; Integrated Security = true");
conn.Open();
DataTable dt = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
List<string> tablenames = new List<string>();
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
     string table = (string)dr[2];
     if((string)dr[1] == "dbo"){
          //Creating a list of table names for "dbo" schema
          tablenames.Add(table);
     }
}
foreach(string table in tablenames){
     if(true){
          SqlDataReader reader = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + table, conn).ExecuteReader();
          //Iterating the entire list of table names and getting the column names
          for(int column = 0; column < reader.FieldCount; column++){
               Console.WriteLine("Catalog - dbo - " + table + " - " + reader.GetName(column));
          }
          reader.Close();
     }
}
Console.WriteLine("END");
Console.ReadLine();
```

However, the list that I get doesn't display (among others) the first table "AccountBillingCode", even though I know it's contained within the list of strings.
If I change the statement:

```
if(true)
```

by

```
if(table.StartsWith('A'))
```

Then, "AccountBillingCode" is listed in the output.

I don't understand why there are some tables getting excluded from my code.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `if (true)` is always true, what's its function there? BTW, your select statement should include the schema `SELECT * FROM dbo.tableName`

Comment: None. I added it there just to verify that if change that by `if(table.StartsWith('A'))` then I actually see the content from "AccountBillingCode"

Comment: Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES you get  the list of table i.e `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` or you can query over `sys.schemas` . Is this what you looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database

Comment: I have sorted the list before getting the column names and I obtain more results. But I still don't understand what could be failing.

Comment: Use `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`; don't write a wretched loop like this.

Comment: Wretched... Ok...

Comment: Sidep point: connection, command and reader objects need `using` to dispose them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there's nothing wrong with the code. It's just the code is too long for the Console, and when copying from there, the content at the top is missing.
Disappointing mystery this time. Sorry! Thanks for the answers anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this as an idea.

```
select 
t.name,c.name
from
sys.tables as t
left join sys.columns as c on t.object_id=c.object_id
order by t.name,c.column_id
```