# SQL query tables by name from list of table names and check they have a column with a certain name

Tags: sql

I have a schema (Main schema) with a list of available tables. Each table has a column which I want to check if it is there.

For example:

```
TheMainSchema:
    table1
    table2
    table3
    table4
    table5
```

Sample of tables:

table1:

```
Id    Row    i_am_important 
____  _____  ______________
1     row1   row1
2     row2   row2
```

table2:

```
Id    Row    i_am_important 
____  _____  ______________
1     row1   row1
2     row2   row2
```

table3:

```
Id    Row    else
____  _____  ______________
1     row1   row1
2     row2   row2
```

The query looks for the important column, if it is there it means the results should be returned.

In this case the query's output would be: table1,table2

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Use system tables to check for existing of column in table.  the issue is we don't know what RDBMS and thus how the system tables are accessed.  For example: Oracle might use `ALL_TAB_COLS`, while in another RDBMS , you may access `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420741/getting-list-of-tables-and-fields-in-each-in-a-database for more info