# Search of table names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I use the following to search for strings within the stored procedures of a specific database:

```
USE DBname
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%xxx%'
```

Is it easy to amend the above so that it searches Table names in a specific db "DBname" ?

Comment: **See Also**: [How do I get list of all tables in a database using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175415/1366033)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I'm using this and works fine

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%%'
```

Comment: Includes views too :-)

Comment: Works for views and tables.

Comment: use SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME LIKE '%%' for stored procedure.

Comment: I suggest to use `ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`, to make the query case insensitive

Comment: `LIKE` is case-insensitive in SQL Server

Answer (score 92):

```
select name
  from DBname.sys.tables
 where name like '%xxx%'
   and is_ms_shipped = 0; -- << comment out if you really want to see them
```

Comment: commenting out the line `and is_ms_shipped = 0;` doesn't seem to do much

Comment: The only thing it normally hides are the database diagram support tables, or is there only one. It's more useful when looking for functions/procedures.

Comment: Why not add schema names?

select  t.schema_id,
   s.name,
   t.Name
from  DBNAME.sys.tables as t
inner join DBNAME.sys.schemas as s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where  t.name like '%yourtabletosearch%'
and   is_ms_shipped = 0

Answer (score 16):

If you want to look in all tables in all Databases server-wide and get output you can make use of the undocumented [sp_MSforeachdb](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx) procedure:

```
sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT "?" AS DB, * FROM [?].sys.tables WHERE name like ''%Table_Names%'''
```

Comment: This answer is the only useful one if you don't know which database a table might be in

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the Filter button to filter tables with a certain string in it.
You can do the same with stored procedures and views.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you want to pass the database name as a parameter and not just run:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    DBName.sys.tables
WHERE   Name LIKE '%XXX%'
```

If so, you could use dynamic SQL to add the dbname to the query:

```
DECLARE @DBName NVARCHAR(200) = 'YourDBName',
        @TableName NVARCHAR(200) = 'SomeString';

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM master.sys.databases WHERE Name = @DBName)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'DATABASE NOT FOUND';
        RETURN;
    END;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '  SELECT  Name
                                FROM    ' + QUOTENAME(@DBName) + '.sys.tables
                                WHERE   Name LIKE ''%'' + @Table + ''%''';

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, N'@Table NVARCHAR(200)', @TableName;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer case-insensitive searching:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME ILIKE '%%'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE Lower(TABLE_NAME) LIKE Lower('%%')
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to @[RichardTheKiwi]'s answer.

Whenever I search for a list of tables, in general I want to select from all of them or delete them. Below is a script that generates those scripts for you.

The generated select script also adds a tableName column so you know what table you're looking at:

```
select 'select ''' + name + ''' as TableName, * from ' + name as SelectTable,
'delete from ' + name as DeleteTable
from sys.tables
where name like '%xxxx%'
and is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use the show command.

```
show tables like '%tableName%'
```

Comment: This is MySQL syntax on a question tagged sql-server

Answer (score 2):

I want to post a simple solution for every schema you've got. If you are using MySQL DB, you can simply get from your schema all the table's name and add the WHERE-LIKE condition on it. You also could do it with the usual command line as follows:

```
SHOW TABLES WHERE tables_in_<your_shcema_name> LIKE '%<table_partial_name>%';
```

where `tables_in_<your_shcema_name>` returns the column's name of `SHOW TABLES` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below :

```
Select * from sys.tables where name like '%yourtablename%'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will working fine....

SELECT * FROM sys.TABLES
WHERE name LIKE '%%'

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 10 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.