# Using External Mapping for Verification

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql, mapping

I'm trying to validate a customer's SQL server database by using external mapping. I want to create the mapping file on my developing computer and use it to verify the customer's server database contains all of the fields, primary keys etc. Is this possible, especially if I add a new table, can I compare the mapping file against the context retrieved from the customer server database?

Comment: I'm more or less wondering if this database to object mapping can be performed on a customer's server db and then compared against a "key" mapping file so that SQL statements can be produced to correct the differences.

Comment: Its possible, although it may be a pain to implement. What database are you using?  Implementations might vary between MsSql, MySQL, etc.

Comment: The project is using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Im starting to shift gears into using queries like described here to validate the customer's DB, then generating SQL to make any changes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql  I'm still open for ideas though.