# How can I dynamically fetch tables from MsSql database using dropdown in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="account-content">
            <option value="" onclick="tbl_city"> All</option>
            <option value="">City</option>
            <option value="">State</option>
            <option value="">Country</option>
            <option value="">Project</option>
            <option value="">Project Detail</option>
            <option value="">Project Category</option>
            <option value="">User</option>
            <option value="">User Detail</option>
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: which version of mssql are you using ? can you give more detailed requirement ? Use following link for the SQL and then load your dropdown with the results of the SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql

Comment: i using sql server 2005

Comment: ok i fetch the tabels but how to bind tabels name in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Use Entity Framework. Bind data to the gridview and use SelectedIndexChanged property of DropDownList to Redirect to that page . you can use something like this:

```
        private DataEntities dataContext;
          dataContext = new DataEntities1();
         gv.DataSource = dataContext.objectName.ToList<TEntity>();
         gv.DataBind();
```

Comment: i want to display table name in dropdown list dynamically

Comment: Check the below link for the solution. I hope it helps:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/420721/how-to-get-database-tables-names-into-dropdown-list-box