# Defining a metamodel

Tags: uml, metadata, metamodel

My question might sound very stupid. But, can anyone please tell me what exactly a metamodel is. I know the technical definition and I have read a lot of papers on metamodels, but I dont seem to get the hang of it.

Suppose I have two classes like this:

```
class A{
    int m_a;
public:
    A(int a);
    void foo();
}; 

class B{
    int m_b;
public:
    B(int b);
    void bar();
};
```

Can anyone please tell me what information my metamodel will contain.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A metamodel describes the model you are using.

Normally you would look at your example and see that there are two entities here : **[A]** and **[B]**. There is no relationship between them so you wouldn't draw a line. You could also describe its methods and parameters.

A Meta-model would look at the elements which make up your model. And in this case you could list these things : **[class], [method], [constructor], [field]**. You could draw a line between class and method *(1-to-many)*, as a class can have many methods (in general). You could also do the same to constructor and to field.

Have a look on google for the UML Metamodel - it describes the relationship between all these things like classes/types/methods/behaviour etc. It can get pretty deep pretty quickly, so have fun diving :)

Answer (score 0):

UML metamodel to UML model is like

**1** the T-SQL database tables (hidden inside the `master` database) that contain the data about T-SQL tables to the instances of the T-SQL tables

It is the place where answers to [How do I get list of all tables in a database using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql) come from

(Same concept can be observed in Oracle, FireBird, MySQL and other database engines)

**2** Or it is like the hidden metadata stuff that enables you to use [MSDN - Reflection (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)