# How does a table not being in information_schema or systables happen?

Tags: sql-server, information-schema

I often run into MSSQL databases that have many more tables than are listed in `information_schema` or `systables`.

For example, I'm [querying a database right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql) but only getting the tables `spt_fallback_db`, `spt_fallback_dev`, `spt_fallback_usg`, `spt_monitor`, `spt_values`. (1)

**How does this happen?**

And - can it be fixed easily?

(1)  I should clarify that this isn't a permissions issue, as I am sysadmin on the database ; there are around 200 tables and I have full permission on all of them.

Comment: Your results look like they might be names of databases, not tables.  Can you include the SQL query that you are running to get those results?

Comment: Another thought...  Does your connection accidentally have `SET ROWCOUNT 5;` turned on?  (Does any query return more than 5 rows?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DeadZone was right on the money, the query had some issues. 
I was using:

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000) 
SELECT @command = 'SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype=''U'' ' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

But it would only show system tables. So then I switched to a more direct query to see what was going on and was able to view the tables:

```
use MYDATABASENAME;
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype='U'
```