# SSMS how to find entity in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity, ssms, dts

I have been told an entity called table_loader in a database, database_1 in SSMS (version 2008 R2) exists and needs to be fixed.  It is not obviously a stored proc.  It's purpose is to convert an excel spreadsheet to table data.  Is there any easy way to search a database for an entity name in SSMS.

The find function appears to work only with text SQL files as opened in SSMS.

Since originally posting I have found out from a colleague that this entity is a DTS package; however, I believe searching a database for a name is still a useful thing to be able to do, especially if you don't know what "layer" the entity is in with respect to the database folder structure.

Thanks.

Comment: I just found out that in this case it is a "dts package"; however, I believe it is still a useful question to find out how to search a database for an entity (such as stored proc) by name, if you don't know what exact "layer" in the folder structure it is in.  Thanks.

Comment: For a DTS package, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645945(v=sql.105).aspx  the answer is essentially under Management --> Legacy --> Data Transformation Services   ; however, a more general search for any entity would still be useful, if someone knows how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great, free, tool is Red-Gate SQL Search. It lets you search for just about any object from SSMS in a very user-friendly manner. http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/. You just type in the object name and it will search across databases and object types and display what it finds. I like it because it also searches within sproc text and such which can be very helpful, depending on what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you open up a query window in SSMS you can use the below SQL to do a wildcard search:

```
USE [dbname]
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name like '%table_loader%'
```

This thread has got some good queries and lists the xtype meanings (sproc, table, key etc):

[How do I get list of all tables in a database using TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql)