# Locating a table in the database

Tags: sql-server

When I run the following query I get the results as expected.

```
select * from [Beep].[Bopp]
```

Then, I ran the query below to "find" the table.

```
select * from sys.objects 
where type='U'
and name like '%Bopp%'
```

It finds the table and lists the row describing it. However, I can't see any reference to *Beep* there. The name only contains *Bopp*, so I'm guessing that there a key that I need to look up but I don't know which column that is nor in what table to look it up.

## edit

Based on the comments, I improved the query but I'm still not sure in what table to look up the actual name of the schema. The following gives me **waaay** to many hits (and setting the type didn't actually give me anything *Beep*-like.

```
select * from sys.tables t
left join sys.objects s 
  on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where t.name like '%Bopp%'
```

I checked the objects for the specific name like so.

```
select * from sys.objects
where name like '%Beep%'
```

To my surprise, I didn't see any hits at all. Where is the little *Beep*-y thing hiding?!

Comment: Beep is the schema. Check schema_id. Why are you using `sys.objects` instead of `sys.tables` anyway? `sys.objects` contains generic information

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using that because of [this reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql) (first hit on Google for "sql server table name"). Yours is probably better - wasn't aware of it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please view the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beep is the schema name for which you should attach another sys table like so:

```
select sys.schemas.name as schema_name, sys.objects.name as object_name
from sys.objects
INNER JOIN sys.schemas ON sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
where type='U'
and sys.objects.name like '%Bopp%'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `schema_name()` function against the `schema_id` column of `sys.objects`, like so:

```
select schema_name([schema_id]) from sys.objects where [name] like '%Bopp%';
```

Alternatively, you can query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, which has a `TABLE_SCHEMA` column that gives the name of the schema rather than its id.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'Bopp';
```

Comment: Actually, yours solved my issue too but I already accepted @emacsuser reply and it won't let me change it (although you'll have the moral victory here because I see your post is dated one hour prior to theirs). No idea how I could have missed it. Sorry.