# What internal tables are automatically created by Django?

Tags: django

I'm working on blacklisting these for the data analysis tool [Metabase](http://www.metabase.com/).

I can't find any lists anywhere that specify which tables the framework creates.

So far from looking at some projects I have:

- django_admin_log
- django_content_type
- django_session
- django_site
- south_migrationhistory

Am I missing anything?

Comment: you need to tell what the version of django is that you are using. south_migrationhistory is not default django but made by south which many people consider an integral part of django but actually isn't

Comment: Right, I'm trying to cover any and all tables from any version of Django that's likely to still be in use today. I know Django 1.7 introduced a built-in migration framework but I can't remember what its migration table is called off the top of my head :)

Comment: that table is called django_migrations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your database, you could find the appropriate command and see all the tables created.

PostgreSQL :

- \list or \l: list all databases
- \dt: list all tables in the current database

MySQL :

- show tables;

Similarly for other db [SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql), [Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205736/get-list-of-all-tables-in-oracle)

The actual list might depend on which apps have been enabled and third party plugins are used. If you want to find all the tables (without any 3rd party app), easiest way might be to create a project and enable all the apps in settings.

Here's an example for Django 1.9  :

> auth_group auth_group_premissions auth_permission django_content_type
>   django_migrations django_session django_site user user_groups
>   user_user_permissions