# Get recent 10 entries from all tables

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to get last entry from all tables? I even did not find way to query all tables, tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM *
```

Comment: Possible duplicate, show all tables in sql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql

Comment: Tables have to be named explicitly in queries, you can't use variables or patterns. You'll need to write dynamic SQL that gets the table names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can do whatever you want in SQL, this query will give you 10 last data from your table, there we go:

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

put table name and id number which is primary key. you can also put any number in `LIMIT 5` like this!

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME` FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME RLIKE '_posts' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC LIMIT 10`
```

think about the data which you want to fetch, so place the row's name after `ORDER BY`. it's done!

don't forget to study in W3school.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably understood me wrong. This query displays all tables: `SELECT 'TABLE_NAME' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME RLIKE '_posts'` How to use this as dynamic table list?

Comment: Does same thing as code in first comment, I tried to use it as FROM table list. Thanks for trying though.